# Пишу на С, присваиваю переменной значение ноля, но после сравнения значение неверно меняется

Tags: c

Сам я только начал с языком знакомиться, многого не знаю, но вот попытался упростить конструкцию if/else.
Выводил сначала шесть, потом семь стало.

```
{   int a, b, c = 0;

    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    scanf_s("%d", &b);
    c = a < b ? (a + b) : printf("False \n");
    printf("%d \n", c);
    return 0;    }
```

Comment: Что значит "неверно меняется"? В чем заключается "неверность"?

Comment: Я представлял, что при a > b будет выводить всё равно ноль. 
Надо было уточнить это, извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> printf("False \n")
> ```

возвращает количество выведенных на экран символов, а именно 7.

> ```
> c = a < b ? (a + b) : printf("False \n");
> ```

Вот так будет как ты ожидаешь:

```
a < b ? (c = a + b) : printf("False \n");
```

но так делать не надо. Во-первых, неудобно, во-вторых, с int'ом-то работает, но типы частей далеко не всегда окажутся совместимыми - хотя результат никуда не присваивается, он всё равно должен быть корректен.

Comment: Как так выходит, что количество символов присваивается в с?

Comment: Эм.. У тебя так код написан. Если a<b, вычислить сумму, иначе выполнить printf. Результат присвоить в `c`.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Андрей, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так вы же сами явно присвоили переменной `c` новое значение в строчке

```
c = a < b ? (a + b) : printf("False \n");
```

Именно это новое значение вы и видите.

Comment: Замысел был, чтобы выводилось "false", когда a > b.
То есть, часть после двоеточия присваивает c количество символов?